# Can we get data in AfterAll function to afterLaunch in protractor

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I am using protractor-cucumber framework(protractor 5.2.2 and cucumber 3.2.0).I am running my protractor script as distributed test execution in multiple browsers.So after each browser execution, i will get an array in AfterAll function.I need to get these data to afterLaunch. So that i can mail these data from afterLaunch, only once, after the execution of all browsers.If i am trying to mail these data from AfterAll function, No.of mails are more.So i need to consolidate data from each AfterAll function to afterLaunch.How can i do this?Can anyone help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

const page = require('../Test_pages')
let Page = new page.Pom();

const helpers = require('../helpers');
let help = new helpers.helpers();



global.before(function () {
    chai.should();
    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    var sf = '{}'
    this.fail = JSON.parse(sf);
    this.pass = JSON.parse(sf);
    this._pass = JSON.parse(sf);
});
afterEach(function () {

});
after(function () {

    console.log(this.fail);
    // will display all property you have added



    return Page.fail(this.fail);
    // call the fail method in pages file


});
```

In your step definition file

```
this.fail[`${testsuite}_${envcode}`] = [{ "pass": false, "testcode": `${testcode}`, "global": `${globalsrc}`, "env": `${envcode}`, "testsuite": `${testsuite}`, "ext3": `${type}` }];
```

Now you can use this JSON object to hold the state of execution by creating a property for each test. I have created a property for each execution with combination of  testsuite and envcode names.

You use this.fail in all hooks function or even write this data to a file by converting it to a String. Later you can read it again.

```
   var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(this.fail);
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile("test_input.json", jsonStr, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```